# Are there words in which the letter D is pronounced like T (and they are not -ed)?

Tags: pronunciation

Are there words in which the letter **D** is pronounced like **T** (and they are not those words which ending with the past tense suffix of -ed)?

Comment: It's hard to think of examples.  Even German loanwords that end in "-d" (which would be pronounced -t in German) are often pronounced "d" in English.  For example, ODO gives only /d/ pronunciations with "hinterland", "dachshund" and "wunderkind".  M-W, though, gives /-t/ pronunciations with "dachshund" and "wunderkind", although it also gives /-d/ variants for both.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "pronounced like T", certain words where /d/ comes after /s/ or before coda /θ/ might count. To my ear, *disdain* sounds like "distain", and *breadth* sounds like "bretth".

In English, the "voiced" plosive phonemes /d/, /b/ and /g/ are not always strongly voiced, and sometimes they may show partial assimilation when adjacent to voiceless obstruents. A "devoiced" /d/ sounds quite similar to an unaspirated /t/ (I don't know enough to say if an actual merger is possible).
For example, I find it hard to hear a difference between the sound of "sd" /sd/ in words like *mi**sd**eed, mi**sd**emeanor, di**sd**ain* and the sound of "st" /st/ in words like *mi**st**ake, mi**st**y, su**st**ain*.

I also hear regressive assimilation of voicelessness in my pronunciation of the words *width, breadth, hundredth*: the "dth" /dθ/ in these words sounds a lot like the /tθ/ in *eighth.*

When /d/ comes before a voiceless obstruent that is not in the same syllable, it may be phonetically devoiced, but the phonological opposition with /t/ is generally still clearly marked by the length (or in some accents, quality) of the preceding vowel. So a word like *bloodthirsty* does not sound like (a hypothetical word) "blutthirsty".

Answer (score 1):

None of the answerers has mentioned the word in which the D is pronounced /t/.

 As far as I know, there is only one English word in which the D is pronounced /t/. And it is ***midst***.

According to [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/midst), *midst* has two pronunciations; /mɪtst/ and /midst/. /mɪtst/ is much more prevalent than /midst/.

There are also some other words in which the D gets devoiced like handpick, midpoint, grandstand etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the reverse: **T**s are often pronounced like soft **D**s in American English when the consonant appears in the middle of the word and when the syllable is not stressed. For example:

> Metal
>
> Butter
>
> Cattle

Keep in mind, it's not consistent, and the pronunciation might be different from word to word and from person to person.

But I can't think of any words where the **D** is pronounced **T**.

More info here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13980/why-is-t-sometimes-pronounced-like-d-in-american-english

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes words spelled with medial 'dd' will be pronounced in some regional dialects closer to a /t/.  This happens where I live.

> With this heavy rain, the track is sloppy,
>   so I'm putting my money on a mudder.

/mutr/

> Left full rudder!

/rutr/